# https network call ssl implementation using Javascript (Cordova)

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, ssl, https

In my cordova application, I am using https api calls using java script. In android platform it is working as expected. But the iOS api was not working with my iPad. When I investigated more, I found that it is related to ssl habndshake. I have added the following method to my app delegate

```
 @implementation NSURLRequest(DataController)
 + (BOOL)allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:(NSString *)host{
     return YES;
   }
```

Now the api is working fine. But came to know that this is not recommended when application is uploaded to iTunes store.  In native applications apple recommends to implement NSURLProtectionSpace  api. I wish to know how this can be accomplished in cordova platform?

Comment: You are effectively disabling the validation of the certificate and thus make man in the middle attacks possible. Instead of disabling validation  you should find out why the certificate could not be validated and make sure it gets properly validated.

Comment: Probably the client or server doesn't support ssl.  In any matter you should switch to the more modern Tls v 1.2

Comment: In cordova using java script how we can validate the certificate. ie, the similar implementation of NSURLProtectionSpace  @SteffenUllrich

Comment: @marshalcraft the same api call is working in android devices. The problem is when api invoked from iOS devices. So switching to TLS will make sense?

Comment: First, switching to tls may not fix the underlying issue, however first and for most in 2016 you should be implementing https with tls rather than ssl which has several vulnerabilities. Also in future servers may begin to no longer support ssl as some have already.

Comment: Given the information in https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/security/ I would suggest that there is no platform independent way and thus they don't offer a way handling certificate validation in Javascript. Apart from that I would recommend to use a properly issued certificate so you don't need to override or even completly disable certificate checking.

Comment: @marshalcraft: this is not an issue of SSL vs. TLS which are basically the same (TLS 1.0 is SSL 3.1). This is an issue of certificate validation which is not related to a specific SSL/TLS version.

Comment: The handshake is an entirely automated process. The exact way a handshake would fail necessarily due to the certificate verification is if the client does not have a root certificate from the signing authority of which the host's certificate is linked to.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich ssl is a deprecated encryption protocol, that is what I'm saying about ssl. And he should be using ssl v 3.3